# Select a checkBox and get the associated text in separate line

Tags: jquery

This is the solution of the problem with getting the associated text of check Box in separate Line when the name is same.

HTML Code-

```
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="5" type="checkbox"> I do not need any unique graphics designed (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="6" type="checkbox"> I will supply images (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="7" type="checkbox"> I have a template but it needs minor customization (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="8" type="checkbox"> I need a template customized (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="9" type="checkbox"> I would like a custom design created for my site (0 Hours)</p>
```

jQuery Code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        var $check = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        $check.each(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            var did = $('input[type=checkbox][value='+id+']:checked').closest('p').text();

        });
    });
});
```

The did variable store the associated text with respect to value of that checkBox.

Comment: You should place the text in a label. Thats What its for in the first place. U Then csn target it with `next()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function SelectallColorsForStyle(e, eval) {
        if (e.checked) {
            $(":checkbox[value=" + eval + "]").prop("checked", e.checked);

            if (!$('input.checkboxselection[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
                $("#CHK_STY_ALL").prop("checked", true);

            if (!$('input.chk_clr_ind[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
                $("#chk_clr_sel_all").prop("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $(":checkbox[value=" + eval + "]").attr('checked', false);
            $("#CHK_STY_ALL").attr("checked", false);
            $("#chk_clr_sel_all").attr("checked", false);
        }
    }
```

above code runs with same value. you can change it to name as per your requirement.

Refference [DEMO](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/01/select-all-child-items-by-selecting.html)

Comment: Just a suggestion whenever you give a answer try to explain what's going in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    First thing I dont understand why you are using '$' for javascript variable declaration and this is wrong.

    Next thing you have a bad logic.

    try this:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').click(function(){ // whenever  an input tag is clicked not sure why you want to run this for all inputs like text, textarea etc
             $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){//for every input of kind checkbox 
                if($(this).is(':checked')){//check if this instance of check box is checked
                var id = $(this).val();//if true get the value of this checkbox 
                            var did = $('input[type=checkbox][value='+id+']:checked').closest('p').innerhtml();//for matching input type checkbox and value get the closest P and get its innerhtml. 
//warning: here you will get 2 closest P's for every checkbox except for first 
    }

            });
        });
    });
        </script>
```

the above script produces output which I'm unsure is same as what you desired. But It will surely help you to make amendments and achieve what you're trying for

Comment: ,Thanks for your co-operation, Here i just give a portion of code, I have radio button as well, And i need this for making a calculation when click on any of the buttons. I want to tell you that why you said my logic is bad??? I am not sure why you tell this, but if it is then i have to do the good one.

Comment: bad logic in the sense you are coding something and expecting something else to happen for instance you were using .html() to get the inner text of a P,which is wrong